# argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number' typescript in visual studio

Tags: asp.net, typescript, visual-studio-2015, resharper, splice

I am using TypeScript in a asp.net solution in visual studio and I have the following:

[image]

```
    removeTabItem(tab: TabItem) {
        for (const i in this.tabs) {
            if (this.tabs[i].id === tab.id) {
                this.tabs.splice(i, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (this.activeTab != null && this.activeTab.id === tab.id) this.activeTab = null;
    }
```

Note that I have installed TypeScript for Visual Studio 2015 and Resharper. 
I am using VS 2015 enterprise.

Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number' typescript in visual studio

Change `this.tabs.splice(i, 1);` to `this.tabs.splice(+i, 1);`

This will convert that string to a number.

Comment: yup, this works, but It's curious, because I have this solution from team foundation server and this code works without the +1 to my other team mates. but good answer, thx

Comment: Kind of ugly, but better than converting to "old-school" for-loop.

Comment: Do your other team mates use the same version of TypeScript? It seems everyone should get this error.

Comment: we have the same version, I checked in te packages.config, should I check somewhere else? this is weird